# Vertical white space between 2 DIV elements

Tags: html, css

I have 4 DIVs and I need them all to be sticked together. I have a white space between and only between first 2 DIVs and I *don't know why*. Any advices and a possible explanation? I don't have any padding of so, making this quite annoying.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: FONT;
  src: url(Montserrat-Regular.ttf);
}
p.title1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
p.title2 {
  font-size: 3em;
}
div.surf1 {
  display: block;
  /*background-image: url("surf1.jpg");*/
  background: #41c3ac;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 600px;
}
div.surf2 {
  display: block;
  background: #41c3ac;
  height: 600px;
}
div.surf3 {
  display: block;
  background: #ff6b57;
  height: 600px;
}
div.surf4 {
  display: block;
  background: #8C78B1;
  height: 600px;
}
div.text1 {
  padding-top: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
div.button {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #e7dd84;
  background-color: rgba(236, 229, 167, 0.2);
  color: #e7dd84;
  transition: 0.35s;
}
div.button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-color: white;
  transition: 0.35s;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: FONT;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<div class="surf1">
  <div class="text1">
    <b>Welcome to smartlearning.com, <br>the place where you can <br>learn and practice English</b>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="button">
    Go to site
  </div>
</div>
<div class="surf2">
  <p class="title1">Interractive games</p>
  <ul style="font-size: 1.5em">
    <li>We have different types of games you can play, testing your abilities to recognise objects, multiple choise exercices and also putting you to the test of spotting mistakes.</li>
    <li>Those games are designed to help you learn and practice english by combining fun with hard-working.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="surf3"></div>
<div class="surf4"></div>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: margin-bottom: -40px; on your div.surf1 is an option to get rid of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `margin-top` on the nested `p` element is [collapsing vertically](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins), which essentially creates an equal `margin-top` on the parent `.surf2` element (that is why you are seeing a space).

According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins), this doesn't occur if you establish a new block formatting context, which means that one option would be to set the `overflow` of the `.surf2` element to something other than the default value `visible`. Changing it to `auto` or `hidden` would resolve the issue.

```
.surf2 {
  background: #41c3ac;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: FONT;
  src: url(Montserrat-Regular.ttf);
}
p.title1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
p.title2 {
  font-size: 3em;
}
div.surf1 {
  display: block;
  /*background-image: url("surf1.jpg");*/
  background: #41c3ac;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 600px;
}
div.surf2 {
  display: block;
  background: #41c3ac;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: auto;
}
div.surf3 {
  display: block;
  background: #ff6b57;
  height: 600px;
}
div.surf4 {
  display: block;
  background: #8C78B1;
  height: 600px;
}
div.text1 {
  padding-top: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
div.button {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #e7dd84;
  background-color: rgba(236, 229, 167, 0.2);
  color: #e7dd84;
  transition: 0.35s;
}
div.button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-color: white;
  transition: 0.35s;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: FONT;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<div class="surf1">
  <div class="text1">
    <b>Welcome to smartlearning.com, <br>the place where you can <br>learn and practice English</b>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="button">
    Go to site
  </div>
</div>
<div class="surf2">
  <p class="title1">Interractive games</p>
  <ul style="font-size: 1.5em">
    <li>We have different types of games you can play, testing your abilities to recognise objects, multiple choise exercices and also putting you to the test of spotting mistakes.</li>
    <li>Those games are designed to help you learn and practice english by combining fun with hard-working.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="surf3"></div>
<div class="surf4"></div>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

That's just one work around. See the spec for the specific rules relating to collapsing margins. You could also simply remove the margin from the `p` element.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, also for the reference to that site. It really helped me. But now, the solution with overflow: auto, wouldn't be better to use margin: 0? Is it like with overflow: auto you are fixing the problem, whereas margin: 0 removes the problem? I'm beginner and I would like to know this.

Comment: @Isengardium I guess it depends. Ideally, you would remove the margin, however that assumes that the paragraph element is going to be the first child each time (which may not always be the case). You could always use the `:first-child` pseudo class to remove the margin from the first child.

Answer (score 2):

For all your `surf#` classed elements, set their overflow to `auto`.

It appears that the margin on the children on the 2nd div is pushing the first div up.

I recommend either adding a unifying class to those elements or use this rule:

```
[class^="surf"] {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, also for the reference to that site. It really helped me. But now, the solution with overflow: auto, wouldn't be better to use margin: 0 as someone said here? Is it like you are fixing the problem, whereas margin: 0 removes the problem? I'm beginner and I would like to know this.

Comment: I don't see an advantage either way honestly. Or at least right now I don't. It depends on how you want the rest of the content in those surf divs to flow. You may actually want margin above and below each item. Maybe not, maybe that should be padding. It's totally up to you. As the page's styling starts to scale, things will become more clear I think.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `class="title1"` margin to 0px. ->  `margin: 0;`